# How to decode / view FCM push token?

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging

I have issues with FCM tokens, sometimes it works but often it doesn't work. It tells me sometimes messaging/server-id-mismatch (don't have the eaxt wording here).

Sometimes, it doesn't work with the `admin.messaging().send()`, but works with the `admin.messaging().sendToDevice()` function. Error messages are different from one to the other.

Sometimes my device gives me a non working token, and later when I refresh the token, I get a working one.

Pretty weird, likely due to my test env (http in local, https when on firebase hosting, playing with dev, uat, prod environments...)

To understand better where it comes from, I'm looking for a way to decode the content of the push token, especially get the serverId and other relevant information.

Tried on jwt.io with ES256 encryption but it tells me it is not correct format.

An example token from test env:

daRgOcOsShw:APA91bEqYpLaXhfQd1FGeE_wk6sIzbvI6HLPGQaoo3PhxXU5kFbs2k0dQTTx772e_mEdsUsQDX59MY2OHVnar0KU0Zm8SlIw1KaFq1U0Gj3KGb1C4-GGmuishzEMHmoYIUZItGCmlOgB

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Facing the same issue! Anything new on this?